# Include Claim details with user details in Identity

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm facing issue in accessing the claims part of the user with Identity. We have a scenario which requires collection of users and the claims corresponding to the user.
Basically, Identity provides us with few inbuilt functions for accessing claims of user. But both of these will provide data only specific to the user.

What I wanted to achieve is include the claims as a part of User details so that when required , the list can be directly accessed. Could you please suggest how this could be done.

Comment: How are you getting the users in the first place?

Comment: Share us your current code which is used to retrive the Users, and what claims did you want when retriving users.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it all in one query. However, after fetching your list of users, you can do something like:

```
var claims = await _context.UserClaims.Where(x => users.Select(u => u.Id).Contains(x.UserId)).ToListAsync();
```

Then, for each individual user's claims:

```
var userClaims = claims.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id);
```